# Loop several independent expiration MSG functions

Tags: excel, vba

This codes work perfect and shows up a message if anyone of my customers license has expired (one message for all customers). I copy it 12 times to check separately in 12 sheets(months). Everything is OK. So my first question is if there is any way to check all months (sheets) together with one code and show up one message for all months, But told me for each customer expire month. And the second is that I would like in this case that no sheet have expire message to inform me with message that no one expires in no sheet.

```
Sub expire_date_1_15()

    Dim LRow As Long
    Dim LName As String
    Dim LPhone As String
    Dim LResponse As String
    Dim LDiff As Long
    Dim LDays As Long

    LRow = 2   'start at row 2
    LDays = 40 'Warning - Number of days to check for expiration

    With Sheets("1_15")
        'Check the first 37 rows in column C
        While LRow < 36

            'Only check for expired certificate if value in column S is not blank
            If IsDate(.Range("R" & LRow)) Then
                LDiff = .Range("R" & LRow).Value2 - Date
                If (LDiff > 0) And (LDiff <= LDays) Then
                    'Get  names
                    LName = .Range("B" & LRow).value
                    LNphone = .Range("c" & LRow).value
                    LResponse = LResponse & LName & " με αριθμό τηλ. " & LNphone & " λήγει σε " & LDiff & " μέρες." & Chr(10)
                End If
            End If

            LRow = LRow + 1
        Wend
        If CBool(Len(LResponse)) Then _
            MsgBox "Τα συμβόλαια των παρακάτω πελατών για τον μήνα Μάρτιο 2015 : " & Chr(10) & vbCrLf & LResponse, vbCritical, "ΕΝΗΜΕΡΩΣΗ ΛΗΞΗΣ ΣΥΜΒΟΛΑΙΩΝ"

    End With

    Call expire_date_2_15

End Sub

Sub expire_date_2_15()

    Dim LRow As Long
    Dim LName As String
    Dim LPhone As String
    Dim LResponse As String
    Dim LDiff As Long
    Dim LDays As Long

    LRow = 2   'start at row 2
    LDays = 40 'Warning - Number of days to check for expiration

    With Sheets("2_15")
        'Check the first 37 rows in column C
        While LRow < 36

            'Only check for expired certificate if value in column S is not blank
            If IsDate(.Range("R" & LRow)) Then
                LDiff = .Range("R" & LRow).Value2 - Date
                If (LDiff > 0) And (LDiff <= LDays) Then
                    'Get  names
                    LName = .Range("B" & LRow).value
                    LNphone = .Range("c" & LRow).value
                    LResponse = LResponse & LName & " με αριθμό τηλ. " & LNphone & " λήγει σε " & LDiff & " μέρες." & Chr(10)
                End If
            End If

            LRow = LRow + 1
        Wend
        If CBool(Len(LResponse)) Then _
            MsgBox "Τα συμβόλαια των παρακάτω πελατών για τον μήνα Απρίλιο 2015 : " & Chr(10) & vbCrLf & LResponse, vbCritical, "ΕΝΗΜΕΡΩΣΗ ΛΗΞΗΣ ΣΥΜΒΟΛΑΙΩΝ"

    End With

    expire_date_Μάϊος_15

End Sub
```

Comment: Take look at [someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/286598) ;).

Answer (score 0):

As the Sub is always the same for each month except for the name of the sheet, you can re-use it by supplying a call parameter. At the same time, relocate the `MsgBox` code into the month loop subroutine:

```
Sub check_all_sheets()
    Dim month As Integer
    Dim n_expired As Integer

    n_expired = 0
    For month = 1 To 12
        ret = expire_date(month)
        If Len(ret) > 0 Then
            n_expired = n_expired + 1
            MsgBox ("expired: " & ret)
        End If
    Next month
    MsgBox ("Total licences expired: " & n_expired)
End Sub

Function expire_date(month As Integer) As String
    Dim LRow As Long
    Dim LName As String
    Dim LPhone As String
    Dim LResponse As String
    Dim LDiff As Long
    Dim LDays As Long
    Dim sh_name As String

    LRow = 2   'start at row 2
    LDays = 40 'Warning - Number of days to check for expiration
    LResponse = ""

    ' sh_name = CStr(month) & "_15"
    sh_name = MonthName(month) & "_15"  ' e.g. "May_15"
    With Sheets(sh_name)
        'Check the first 37 rows in column C
        While LRow < 36
            'Only check for expired certificate if value in column S is not blank
            If IsDate(.Range("R" & LRow)) Then
                LDiff = .Range("R" & LRow).Value2 - Date
                If (LDiff > 0) And (LDiff <= LDays) Then
                    'Get  names
                    LName = .Range("B" & LRow).Value
                    LNphone = .Range("c" & LRow).Value
                    LResponse = LResponse & LName & " με αριθμό τηλ. " & LNphone & " λήγει σε " & LDiff & " μέρες." & Chr(10)
                End If
            End If
            LRow = LRow + 1
        Wend
    End With
    expire_date = LResponse
End Function
```

BTW, I think the code is not checking the first 37 rows but only rows 2..35.

Comment: I run your code but it seems i have lost it some how. Can you please tell me where i will write my sheets name or other ?. My sheets go like this way MARCH_15 and so on..... Because this way when i run it just for one sheet, it gave me 12 same msg for the same customer.

Comment: I just need only one message which will include all expires customes per month and if it can't be happen i can keep the old code (it work anyway) but i just need a msg to infom me in case i haven't any expires for all months.

Comment: In your question you clearly use numeric sheet names like "1_15". I've added code to have clear text month names anyway. I will leave output handling to you as it is only a minor part of the code.